# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. splitItems(0).toString

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, split

i have this button which i add in row of data however, it give me error, can anyone help me out tell me why is the splitItems(0).ToString cause error, how should i get that value to store in the database

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0
        Dim sc As New StringCollection()
        If ViewState("CurrentTable") IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim dtCurrentTable As DataTable = DirectCast(ViewState("CurrentTable"), DataTable)
            Dim drCurrentRow As DataRow = Nothing
            If dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count < 10 Then
                For i As Integer = 1 To dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count
                    'extract the TextBox values

                    Dim box5 As TextBox = DirectCast(Gridview3.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(1).FindControl("TextBox5"), TextBox)

                    'get the values here

                    Dim box6 As Date
                    box6 = Convert.ToDateTime(box5.Text)
                    Dim box7 As Date = Convert.ToDateTime(box5.Text)



                    sc.Add(box6)



                    rowIndex += 1
                Next

                InsertRecords(sc)
            End If
        Else
            '   lblMessage.Text = "Cannot save as there no information recorded"
            MsgBox("failed")
        End If
    End Sub

 Protected Sub InsertRecords(sc As StringCollection)



        Dim sb As New StringBuilder(String.Empty)

        Dim splitItems As String() = Nothing

        For Each item As String In sc


            If item.Contains(",") Then
                splitItems = item.Split(",".ToCharArray())




            End If
        Next

        Try

            Dim myConn As New SqlConnection
            Dim myCmd As New SqlCommand
            myConn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("mydatabase").ConnectionString
            Dim cmd As String
            cmd = "Insert into Date values (@date) "
            myCmd.CommandText = cmd
            myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
           //error found at this line splitItems(0).ToString()
            myCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@date", splitItems(0).ToString()))


            myCmd.Connection = myConn
            myConn.Open()
            myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            myCmd.Dispose()
            myConn.Dispose()

            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(Page), "Script", "alert('Records Successfuly Saved!');", True)
        Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
            Dim msg As String = "Insert Error:"
            msg += ex.Message

            Throw New Exception(msg)
        Finally
            conn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check with the breakpoint and make sure splitItems has more than one values.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably find that either there are no elements in the splitItems array, or the element splitItem(0) equals "Nothing".

Just briefly looking at your code I wonder if the main problem is in the ForEach at the top of InsertRecords.  I think if sc = {"1/1/2010"} then the "*If item.contains(",")*" will never be true so the date will never be added to the splitItems array. A.K.A the splitItems array would be empty when it hits the ToString line that is throwing the exception.

Comment: orh okay , if it is this sc = {"1/1/2010"}, how am i going to retrieve this item into the database???

Comment: Well if my assumption is correct then one way to fix it would be to remove the if statement from around the item.Split statement.  If you run `splitItems=item.Split(",")` against a string with no commas then splitItems will be a single element array with {"1/1/2010"} as the value (I *think* this is what your code is expecting).  Can you verify that my original assumption is correct?

Comment: yes, you are right, i dont really need the comma at all, only date is inserted, so can you show me how